# Duplicating Discrete Axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The development version of ggplot2 (2.1.0.9001) provides a nice shorthand for creating a secondary axis that is a duplication of the primary axis *if* the original axis is continuous:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = dup_axis()
  )
```

How can a discrete axis be duplicated?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() +
  ...?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322303/issues-with-ggdraw-since-ggplot2-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch_axis_position is now deprecated, and in fact is gone. [Issues with ggdraw since ggplot2 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322303/)

Outdated material: 
The cowplot library  <strike>has</strike>  used to have that that facility:

```
library(cowplot)
gpv <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, factor(cyl))) + 
   geom_point()
ggdraw( switch_axis_position( gpv, axis="y", keep="y"))
```

Don't forget that you need to `print` grid-based graphics when sending to a file:

```
png()
  print(ggdraw(switch_axis_position(gpv, axis="y", keep="y")) )
dev.off()
#quartz 
#     2
```

[image]

Comment: The `switch_axis_position` is now deprecated, and in fact is gone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322303/issues-with-ggdraw-since-ggplot2-update

Comment: I think this question and answer should be kept. I just wanted to add a comment so that if anyone came to this post (by searching on keywords - like me !!), then they would realize why that function didn't exist anymore. I'm still trying to figure out a way to duplicate a discrete y-axis.

Comment: I think editing the question will save future users time.