# Duplicating (and modifying) discrete axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to duplicate the left-side Y-axis on a ggplot2 plot onto the right side, and then change the tick labels for a discrete (categorical) axis.

I've read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134648/duplicating-discrete-axis-in-ggplot2), however as can be seen [on the package's repo page](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/d10f9cad3123594e2925e680b8b2b59856c8833f/vignettes/axis_position.Rmd), the `switch_axis_position()` function has been removed from the `cowplot` package (the author cited (forthcoming?) native functionality in ggplot2).

I've seen the [reference](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) page on secondary axes in ggplot2, however all the examples in that document use `scale_y_continuous` rather than `scale_y_discrete`. And, indeed, when I try to use the discrete function, I get the error:

```
Error in discrete_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend"), "position_d",  : 
unused argument (sec.axis = <environment>)
```

Is there anyway to do this with ggplot2? Even a completely hacked solution will suffice for me. Thanks in advance. (MREs below)

```
library(ggplot2)

# Working continuous plot with 2 axes
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg))  + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+10))


# Working discrete plot with 1 axis
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, as.factor(mpg)))  + 
    geom_point() 


# Broken discrete plot with 2 axes
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, as.factor(mpg)))  + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_discrete(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+10))
```

Comment: looking at the source of `scale_y_discrete` there is no option / argument for specifying the secondary axis. So any solution will probably have to be a hack.

Comment: I raised an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171) over at ggplot to support `sec.axis` natively in `scale_y/x_discrete()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take your discrete factor and represent it numerically. Then you can mirror it and relabel the ticks to be the factor levels instead of numbers.

```
library(ggplot2)

irislabs1 <- levels(iris$Species)
irislabs2 <- c("foo", "bar", "buzz")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, as.numeric(Species))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:length(irislabs1),
                     labels = irislabs1,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,
                                         breaks = 1:length(irislabs2),
                                         labels = irislabs2))
```

Then fiddle with the `expand =` argument in the scale as needed to more closely imitate the default discrete scale.

[image]

Comment: as per ggplot help "The defaults are c(0.05, 0) for continuous variables, and c(0, 0.6) for discrete variables."
for me expand = c(0,0.6) gave really nice results

Comment: Just found this again. Is there still no better way to do it? Anyone knows an easier way by now?

Comment: @TobiO I haven't followed development on ggplot for a couple years, but you can always file a bug report on their github repo with a good reprex.

Comment: I found this again, because I was looking for a solution and only found a feature request from a few weeks after this was done, with a similar suggestion as yours :-)

Comment: There is actually an open issue on Github, put a comment there to let the team know you're still interested: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171