# ggplot how to add labels on a second axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the example data below and the respective plot, I simply want to add text for each of the three cyl groups at the top, e.g. for cyl = 4, I want to add a label like "abc", for cyl = 6 a label like "xyz" and so on.

I know that ggplot doesn't like secondary axes, and in my case I don't even want to display additional data, I just want to add second/alternative axis labels.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars |>
  mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl)) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = cyl, y = gear, fill = disp))
```

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `sec_axis` takes many of the same arguments as `scale_x_continuous`, including `breaks=` and `labels=`. Just provide an "identity" transform (`~ .`) and provide both arguments, as in 
`... + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = c(4, 6, 8), labels = c("abc", "def", "ghi")))`

Comment: If my comment and the dupe-links don't give you what you need, @-ping me and let me know what's incomplete. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Seems my example wasn't appropriate enough. When the x axis is continuous (like in teh example), your approach works. However, let's assume, the original x axis doens't have numeric values like 4, 6, 8, but instead factor or character values like "A", "B", "C".

Comment: I updated my example accordingly.

Comment: `sec_axis` does not work with discrete data: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171

Comment: All workarounds I've seen have been converting a discrete axis to continuous, and manually controlling both the primary and secondary `breaks=` and `labels=` accordingly. Not awesome, but it can work until that (4+ year old) issue is resolved.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45361904/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/75744690/3358272 as well.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Looking at github, this workaround does the trick in my case: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171#issuecomment-614084750