# Overlaying two plots with different x- and y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a main plot, which is only understandable when one is aware of the underlying data generating process, which again is best illustrated by a plot. Therefore, I would like to show both plots together. The problem is, both plots use entirely different scales. This is how far I have come in a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x=c("borrowing", "ignorant", "borrowing", "ignorant"), y=c(0.9, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8), z=c("same", "same", "diff", "diff"))
myfun <- function(a,b,x){a + x*b}

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_function(data = data.frame(z="diff"), fun=myfun, args=list(a=0, b=2)) +
  geom_function(data = data.frame(z="same"), fun=myfun, args=list(a=0, b=1)) + 
  facet_grid(~z)
```

[image]

This is all fine, except that the geom_function (which is continuous) uses the same scale as geom_point (which is discrete). Ideally, I want to plot the point-geom with a discrete x-axis (with categories "borrowing" and "ignorant") and the function-geom with a continuous x-axis (with x-values from 0 to 20, instead of from 1 to 2 as currently). Is there any possibility to achieve this based on ggplot? Of course, I am open for packages such as gridExtra etc.

Comment: Where is the `inv_logit` function defined? Also I'm not clear on what your desired output is. What exactly do you want the final plot to look like?

Comment: @MrFlick apologies, my MRE was not so reproducible after all. I was finally able to achieve my desired output following the recommendation of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361904/duplicating-and-modifying-discrete-axis-in-ggplot2. If I have time I will post the specific solution to my question for completeness.

Comment: I tried to edit my question but it failed due to "an error occurred".

Comment: Perhaps using the secondary axis option as described here  https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html , and passing your function as an argument to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `facet_wrap` with the `scales = "free_y"` argument. Just change the `facet_grid` line to the following:

```
facet_wrap(~z, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating the axis after converting the discrete x-variable to a continuous does the trick, then rescaling the second axes in the `sex_axis` argument, following the recommendations from this post: [Duplicating (and modifying) discrete axis in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361904/duplicating-and-modifying-discrete-axis-in-ggplot2)

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=as.numeric(as.factor(x))-1,y=y)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(z="diff", tox=myfun(a=-1, b=2, x=0:20), x=0:20), aes(x=x/20, y=tox/100)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(z="same", tox=myfun(a=-4, b=1, x=0:20), x=0:20), aes(x=x/20, y=tox/100)) +
  facet_grid(~z) + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~.x*20, name="Dose")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), "Accuracy", sec.axis=sec_axis(~.x*100, name="Prob. of Tox."))
```

[image]