# Adding secondary Y axis to bubble plot (just characters)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a ggplot question, which I think relates to the function `annotate` or `sec_axis` , but I am not sure how to do this. I've got the following data and code to generate a bubble plot:

```
# generate some mock data
df <- data.frame( Module = c("black","blue","brown"), P = c(1.068242e-12, 2.941035e-40, 6.975126e-12), Bonferroni = c(3.915918e-07, 1.078113e-34, 2.556914e-06 ), EnrichmentRatio = c(2.030865, 2.395059, 1.169325), GO_term = c("GO term 1", "GO term 2", "GO term 3"), "neg.log10.P" = c(11.97133, 39.53150, 11.15645) )

head(df)
  Module            P   Bonferroni EnrichmentRatio   GO_term neg.log10.P
1  black 1.068242e-12 3.915918e-07        2.030865 GO term 1    11.97133
2   blue 2.941035e-40 1.078113e-34        2.395059 GO term 2    39.53150
3  brown 6.975126e-12 2.556914e-06        1.169325 GO term 3    11.15645


# generate the bubble graph
png("top10each_final_top.png", width= 8, height =  6, units = "in", res=300)
 ggplot( df, aes(x=`neg.log10.P`, y=reorder(`Module`, `neg.log10.P`), size = `EnrichmentRatio`, fill = `neg.log10.P`)) +
 geom_point(shape = 21) + 
 scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "E", direction = -1) +
 labs(x = "-log10 P", y= "Module") +
 theme_minimal() +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, face = "bold")) +
 labs(title = "GO terms per module")
dev.off()
```

This is resulting in the following graph:

[image: Bubble graph]

What I want to do is add the respective GO term for that module on a secondary Y axis, on the right. If the first Y axis reads `blue / black / brown` from top down on the left, then the second Y axis on the right need to read `GO term 2 / GO term 1 / GO term 3`. Any suggestions?

I found an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361904/duplicating-and-modifying-discrete-axis-in-ggplot2) question that I think will enable me to do this, but I am not sure how to translate this to my current code, given the reorder function that is needed to plot the bubbles in order of significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a discrete scale does not allow for a secondary axis one option to achieve your desired result would be to switch to a continuous scale which however requires to convert your `factor` `Module` to a numeric  and setting the labels via the scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- df |>
  transform(Module = reorder(Module, neg.log10.P)) |>
  transform(module_num = as.numeric(Module))

breaks <- unique(df$module_num)
labels_y1 <- unique(df$Module)
labels_y2 <- unique(df$GO_term)

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = neg.log10.P,
  y = module_num,
  size = EnrichmentRatio,
  fill = neg.log10.P
)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = breaks,
    labels = labels_y1,
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      labels = labels_y2
    ),
    expand = c(0, .6)
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "E", direction = -1) +
  labs(x = "-log10 P", y = "Module") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, face = "bold")) +
  labs(title = "GO terms per module")
```

[image]