How to create a plot with dual X-axes using ggplot2 in R?
I am trying to create a plot in R that displays two overlapping X-axes:

One for Semana TW (Weeks of This Year).
One for Semana LY (Weeks of Last Year).
The goal is to compare the sales from the last 7 weeks with the sales from the same weeks in the previous year, but shifted 3 weeks forward (this is why I have three zero sales in the Semana TW column).

I was able to create this chart in Python using matplotlib, but I need to replicate it in R using ggplot2 or another plotting library.
Here is the chart I generated in Python:

And this is the data table I used:



Semana TW
Semana LY
Venta TW
Venta LY




W1
WA
1000
1100


W2
WB
800
700


W3
WC
900
1000


W4
WD
1000
1100


W5
WE
1100
1000


W6
WF
1000
1100


W7
WG
900
1000


W8
WH
0
1100


W9
WI
0
1000


W10
WJ
0
1200



In R i tried this code, that gives me a similar result, but its not what im looking for:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# Data setup with correct sorting for Semana TW
Semana_TW <- factor(c('W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10'), levels = c('W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10'))
Semana_LY <- c('WA', 'WB', 'WC', 'WD', 'WE', 'WF', 'WG', 'WH', 'WI', 'WJ')
Venta_TW <- c(1000, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1000, 900, 0, 0, 0)
Venta_LY <- c(1100, 700, 1000, 1100, 1000, 1100, 1000, 1100, 1000, 1200)

# Create the initial data frames for Semana TW and Semana LY
df_TW <- data.frame(Semana = Semana_TW, Ventas_TW = Venta_TW)
df_LY <- data.frame(Semana = Semana_LY, Ventas_LY = Venta_LY)

# Merge the two datasets
df_combined <- data.frame(
  Semana_TW = Semana_TW,
  Semana_LY = Semana_LY,
  Ventas_TW = Venta_TW,
  Ventas_LY = Venta_LY
)

# Convert the data into long format for ggplot (for easy plotting of both series)
df_combined_long <- pivot_longer(df_combined, cols = c("Ventas_TW", "Ventas_LY"), 
                                 names_to = "Tipo_Venta", values_to = "Ventas")

# Create the plot using ggplot2
ggplot(df_combined_long, aes(x = Semana_TW, y = Ventas, color = Tipo_Venta, group = Tipo_Venta)) +
  geom_line() + # Create the line connecting the points
  geom_point() + # Add points for each week
  labs(title = "Ventas Semanas TW vs LY", x = "Semana TW", y = "Ventas") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Ventas_TW" = "blue", "Ventas_LY" = "red")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Semana_LY), vjust = -1, hjust = 1.1, angle = 45) + # Annotate with Semana LY values
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))




Looks like a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361904/duplicating-and-modifying-discrete-axis-in-ggplot2

That's right, thanks Jon!

We can use a continuous x-scale with the sec.axis argument:
ggplot(
  df_combined_long, 
  aes(x = as.numeric(Semana_TW), y = Ventas, color = Tipo_Venta, group = Tipo_Venta)
) +
  geom_line() + # Create the line connecting the points
  geom_point() + # Add points for each week
  labs(title = "Ventas Semanas TW vs LY", x = "Semana TW", y = "Ventas") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Ventas_TW" = "blue", "Ventas_LY" = "red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:nlevels(Semana_TW),
    labels = Semana_TW,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(I, breaks = 1:nlevels(Semana_TW), labels = Semana_LY)
  ) +
    theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0)
  )



worked great, thank you very much!
